# ODE solver for Hamiltonian evolution of a finitely-dimensional pure quantum state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, computational-physics, hamiltonian, simulations

I want to simulate evolution of a finitely-dimensional pure quantum state:

$$\frac{d\psi}{dt} = - i H(t) \psi$$

The wavefunction $\psi$ is a $n$ dimensional complex vector, and the Hamiltonian $H$ is just a $n \times n$ time-dependent matrix.
What is the go-to ordinary differential equation numerical algorithm for this case?

The Euler integration method, i.e. $\psi(t+\Delta t) = (1 - i \Delta t H(t))\psi(t)$, does not suffice as there are large differences between energies.
Sure, there are quite [a few other methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations). However, as the problem is a concrete instance (purely linear, norm-preserving), I guess there might be a preferred one.

Comment: a review I always found useful is this one (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002199919190137A) by Leforsteir et. al., specifically the Chebyshev scheme which they present in page 64 onwards, which can be generalized to time-dependent Hamiltonians using small time steps. but they present other approaches as well

Comment: This question seems like good candidate for the [scicomp.se]…